# Outlook profile keeps asking for password but 2FA doesn't appear

Tags: microsoft-outlook, two-factor-authentication

I have my 365 account signed in to windows and when I initially signed it in to Outlook it asked to verify me by my 2factor app from Microsoft but now it's been a while and I just changed my password, Outlook is "try to connect" and when I put in my new password a white box appears and then disappears, it looks like it's the same size as the window that would ask for my 2factor code...

Comment: I would try going into credential manager and removing the stored credentials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest removing any saved credentials from your windows credential manager, you can open that by:
Press and hold the Windows key and then hit the R key, this will being up the Run dialogue box, typing the below command into your run box will open the credential manager

> control /name Microsoft.CredentialManager

Another idea is to completely remove your 365 account from your windows sign in and then re-add it, go in to windows settings and find Accounts> Access Work or school > select YourAccount@domain.com and press on "Disconnect" then after it's done that press the Connect button above that same spot and re-add the account again

You can also go in to the registry, this could be necessary for older versions of office like 2013 and 2016 sometimes

for 2016(and above) go to:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\Identity
for 2013 go to:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Common\Identity\

Right click in the right hand side window and go to New > DWORD Value
Type in the text:

> EnableADAL
> then once that is the name of the DWORD Value, select it and press Enter/return and set its data value to 1 instead of 0

Reboot the PC and that should be in affect, though on some systems a reboot isn't required it's always advantageous to try it anyway

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).